# Prefer std::swap to container's swap()?

Tags: c++

If `Coll` is a standard container type, `a` and `b` are instances of `Coll`; then, should we **ALWAYS** use `std::swap(a, b)` instead of `a.swap(b)`?

For me, `std::swap(a, b)` is more generic than `a.swap(b)`. However, I just wonder, can this be a best practice? or any counter example?

Comment: A counter example could be the pre-C++11 trick to release memory allocated by containers: `std::vector<int>().swap(v);`. You cannot do this with `std::swap`, since it requires both arguments to be lvalues.

Comment: "more generic" is not necessarily a design goal. Engineering is about making design decisions that reflect the particular circumstances of the problem being solved, not blindly applying rules. Anyone can build a bridge that stands up; it takes an engineer to build one that barely stands up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When there is a member swap function available, it makes sense to prefer it. Why should it exist in the first place, if it does nothing but duplicating the default `std::swap` implementation?

Beyond that, I would distinguish between standard containers and others. In the former case, [`std::swap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) is specialized to do the right thing for your container instance. In the latter case, go with the member swap function.